# How to clip ImageView to CardView size in a framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I have an recyclerview item that contains a cardview at the root. Inside the cardview I have a layout that height set to wrap_content and it all works fine, but what I want to do is have an image that will fill the cardview when its visibility is set to visible. Because the image is a lot larger than the cardview it pushes the height of the cardview down. the Image width is set the fill_parent and the height is set to wrap_content.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- main container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- omitted content -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- overlay image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/completed_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/completed_stamp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I basically want the overlay image to be clipped by the main layout and I'm not sure how to go about it.

The Image is 800 x 800 and the ImageView is set to centerCrop.

I have currently tried:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = mainContainer.getLayoutParams();
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
imageView.requestLayout();
```

in the onBindViewHolder

**EDIT**

Using this code in the onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.ImageView.getLayoutParams().height = holder.CardView.getHeight();
```

This works but what it does is apply the resize to the next occurrence that requires it in the recyclerview list so its not really a solution

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your layout how it looks?

Comment: I can't actually take a screenshot of the issue as its a proprietary app, but if you think of a cardview that is a rectangle that is wider than it is high with wrap_content on height set and overlaying an image that is resized to the width of the cardview but because the image is square it pushes the bottom of the cardview down. I edited the question with further progress I have made

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with this before, you may want to try adding setting the cropToPadding attribute to true in your image view. This may or may not cut some of the image out, but if its something like a profile photo this is good since it will scale depending on device/screen size/density.

Comment: I tried this but to no avail, its not a profile image its basically an image that overlays the entire cardView but expands to cardview to fits its height

Comment: Right on, so it's more of a background image that you'll overlay other content in the frame layout with?

Comment: Its a foreground image set to View.GONE till its needed, Yeah in a framelayout

Comment: I think I've figured out the deal, you may have to set some dimensions on the image view, with out any hard dimensions the cropToPadding attribute will not function correctly. Keep in mind that a CardView is very similar in behavior to a framelayout in the way it positions child elements.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have updated the question to show the settings on the imageview and the basis of the main content of the cardview ;)